# regular expression for .co.uk email

Tags: regex, email

does anyone have an email reg ex for validating email address. some people are putting in .co.ul instead of .co.uk and I need to check for this. Usually I would have a second email confirmation textbox but this project we cannot. cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: Besides the things mentioned in the dupe, check if the email address end with `.co.uk`. But am I only allowed to enter British addresses?

Comment: the user can enter global email but there are a lot of .co.ul for example.

Comment: But then you'll have to fix all typos. Anyway, with regex you cannot know whether an address actually exists or not (but I think that's clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for...... `/\.co\.uk$/i`